# Grails getting error during run. Grails 3.0.0

Tags: java, grails, grails-3.0

C:\Users\lalitk>grails
Usage:
         create-app [NAME] --profile=web
         create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin

| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

C:\Users\lalitk>grails --stacktrace
Usage:
         create-app [NAME] --profile=web
         create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin

| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(GitProfileRepository.groovy:72)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.ListProfilesCommand.handle(ListProfilesCommand.groovy:43)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:173)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.getBaseUsage(GrailsCli.groovy:118)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:162)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null

C:\Users\lalitk>

Answer (score 0):

This error to due to maven was installed in you system..

follow the below steps
 1. delete the c:\Users\.m2 or related directory in windows (Not sure about Unix or Mac but you can find the local cache of maven. Delete .m2 directory)
 2. delete maven related environment variable.
 3. delete ./gradlew
 4. delete environment variable related to groovy also

try to above step.. it will work fine